# Find Edge Indices of Cartesian Product

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools

Given a nested list, I would like to find the *edge* indices of its cartesian product.

```
example_list = [[15], [16, 17], [18], [19], [20], [21]]
```

I can use the following the calculate the cartesian product:

```
c_prod = numpy.stack(list(itertools.product(*example_list)))
```

However, if you image each element as a node, I want to the find the indices of the edges that gave rise to the cartesian product. The result would be:

```
edge_indices = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "the indices of the edges that gave rise to the cartesian product?" I don't get that part

Comment: If you imagine this list as a directed acyclic graph, I want to find the indices of the path that connect the elements. For example, [15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21] has the first connection between the first pair of sublists, and the first connect between the second pair of sublists, so the indices would be [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]. However, something like [0, 1, 0, 0, 0] is not valid because it represents a disjunct path of 15 -> 16, 17 -> 18 for the first two steps.